# Customizing views output- rewrite output to show an image based on key value

Tags: views

I want to use a views template to customize the output of the gender field on my user profile.  The gender field is a select list, and the key values are as follows:

- f (female)
- m (male)
- o (other)

I created a template file, `views-view-field--field-acc-gender.tpl.php`.  I have the images saved in my theme's directory.  I can write an if statement to check against the key value, but how do I get the value of the field?  (This is probably a straightforward question, but I just learned about views templates today.)

I tried the following in `views-view-field--field-acc-gender.tpl.php`:

```
<?php 
if ($output == 'M') {
  print 'male';
}
else if ($output == 'F') {
  print 'female';
}
else {
  print 'other';
}
```

However, my view still simply prints out `M` or `F` instead of `male` or `female`.

Comment: Please show the all code in that template?

Comment: That is all the code that is in the template right now.

Comment: If you know that your getting a value out of $output then assign the replacement string to $output rather than print them. Should probably then print $output after your conditional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to access the data from `$row` array from inside the template file. So:

```
$data = $row->field_field_acc_gender;

// This may not necessarily be the correct structure of your field's data.
// So you may want to do print_r($data) or dpm($data) to see correct structure.
$gender = $data[0]['raw']['value']; 

switch($gender) {
  case 'M':
    print('Male');
    break;
  case 'F':
    print('Female');
    break;
}
```

Comment: I discovered my error-- I was not actually outputting the field, but rather rewriting the output and displaying the value of the field from another.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you want to be using a copy of 'views-view-fields.tpl.php'.

Before the foreach loop on the $fields object you can alter the output.

**Example:**

```
   if ( $fields['FIELD_NAME']->content == 'something' ) {
      // do something else...
   }
```

In your example it would be appear you've gone for the 'single field' option.

You might want to just assign some alternative value to $output then print it after your conditionals.